# nServiceBus with Distributor in a web farm

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I am not sure where the distributor/s should run when there is a number of clients and a number of servers. If I have a single distributor which all clients send to and all servers get work from then surely it is a single point of failure. Is there a way to remove this weak point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd likely run a distributor on a cluster for high-availability.
That being said, you can go so far as to have a separate distributor for each message type and configure your clients to send each message type to its designated distributor. Then you can allocate servers to distributors based on the amount of resources you want to allocate per message type.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Assuming we have multiple servers configured as distributors could they be run behind a Cisco CSS?

Comment: The thing is that the distributor needs to manage state - in the current implementation a queue is used to store that state. In order for that queue to be highly available, you need a cluster. If you open up the source and swap out the queue storage, you can provide a database backed implementation which you likely already have set up to be highly available.